# How are MIME type conflicts handled?

Tags: mime-types

According to [Shared MIME-info Database](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-0.11.html):

> These files have a mime-type element as the root node. The format is as described above. They are created by merging all the mime-type elements from the source files and creating one output file per MIME type. Each file may contain information from multiple source files. The magic, glob and root-XML elements will have been removed.

What if two files contain conflicting information for the same MIME type? Specifically, is it guaranteed that the information from `freedesktop.org.xml` is not overwritten by other XML files?

Comment: Nope, last change wins.